# Height and width view in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want Photoshop to show the exact Height and Width(in pixels) of an item position when I drag it to move. It must be shown right on my canvas. Also need to be shown the lines that align text(or item) with the center or another item. Where can I activate this function from? Pics attached. Thanks in advance[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Ticco, your question is very confusing to me. Are these screenshots from you? If yes, what is the problem? Are you trying to enable Smart Guides? I think the pixel amount when making selections is a default feature that you cannot get rid of. It might not be there in older Photoshop versions.

Comment: Hey, no actually these screenshots are from a video. So I need to activate that feature also for me

Comment: PS CS6 is the earliest version to have these features, I think.

Comment: I think what those numbers show is the "movement" amount rather than the "object" position, at least that seems to be the way in CS6. In other words, hold the shift key down, click on one spot on the object and drag it in one direction, you will see the other direction will show 0.00 since that is not changing. That is what my CS6 shows.

Answer (score 1):

The pixel dimension tool tips will only show when you are modifying an object's size, not when you are moving it around.

You could Cmd + T to put the object into Free Transform mode and see its width and height in the Info panel while you move it around (it's not a tool tip, but the info is there).

Comment: I totally agree... This is the option which I use.. :) My answer is the same :) :)